# PHP issues appending to json file, code results in an array full of null

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, null

I'm trying to append new items to the end of my json file. When the code runs as below, it keeps appending null instead of the new items. I've searched around and haven't found any solutions yet.

Here's the PHP:

```
$_POST["carMake"] = 'toyota'; 
$_POST["startProduction"] = '258147369';
$_POST["endProduction"] = '369258147';

$file = "cars.json";
$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
array_push($jsonArray[], array( 'Make' => $_POST["carMake"], 'Start Prod' => $_POST["startProduction"], 'End Prod' => $_POST["endProduction"] ));
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($jsonArray));

$answer = array ( 'Created' => "true", 'validation' => "Car added");
return json_encode($answer);
```

The intended output is:

```
    [
     {
      "Make":"Toyota",
      "Start Prod":258147369,
      "End Prod":369147258
     },
     {
      "Make":"BMW",
      "start":789456123,
      "end":159487263
     },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_push($jsonArray[], ...` is wrong. You should either do:

```
$jsonArray[] = ...
```

or:

```
array_push($jsonArray, ...
```

not both.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I didnt see that restriction in the documentation. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as PHP manual said that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
$_POST["carMake"] = 'toyota'; 
$_POST["startProduction"] = '258147369';
$_POST["endProduction"] = '369258147';

$file = "cars.json";
$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$jsonArray[]= array( 'Make' => $_POST["carMake"], 'Start Prod' => $_POST["startProduction"], 'End Prod' => $_POST["endProduction"] );
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($jsonArray));

$answer = array ( 'Created' => "true", 'validation' => "Car added");
return json_encode($answer);
```

Comment: Tried this as well and it worked too. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @user2238415 - please search this on documentation page `to add one element to the array it's better to use`